# How to keep a reference to a class on another?

Tags: c++

```cpp
class cars
{
public:
   int price(int x);
}

class colors
{
public:
   int func1;
   int func2;
   cars fusca; // <---- error 'unknown override specified'
}

int colors::func1(...)
{
    //cars fusca;
    //this->cars = cars;  // <-- ???
}

int colors::func2(..)
{
   this->fusca.price(10);
}
```

How do I "define" an instance of `cars` inside of the class `colors` in which I could use in any other `colors::...` function?

If I declare `cars fusca` inside of `colors` i get this error: 'unknown override specified'

Comment: You are trying to declare a data member of type `Cars`, but your program doesn't declare any such type. It declares a different type, `cars`.

Comment: OT: If you are going to use lower case names for your variables you may want to use initial caps for the class name so you don't try to add a variable `cars cars;` Also doesn't the class represent a single car? Maybe you want to drop the plural and make your class Car and have a car instance. But why does colors have a car. Wouldn't a car have a color instead?

Comment: You are also using `this->cars` when you could use `cars`, and you seem to intend to have a variable and a class whose names differ only by the capitalization of one letter, which ought to get your knuckles rapped by the teacher.

Comment: Additionally, missing semicolons strongly suggest that this is not the real code with the described compilation errors. An attempt to compile the shown code will fails with syntax errors much earlier than the described error. Please show real code, that meets all requirements for a [mre], as described in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a vector of smart pointers, like in the example below.

Keeping references is too dangerous as you have to control lifetimes very tightly (if that is what you meant by "reference").

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class car
{
public:
   int price(int x);
};

class colors
{
public:
   void func1();
   void func2();
   using car_ptr = std::shared_ptr<car>;
   using car_vector = std::vector<car_ptr>;
   car_vector cars; 
};

void colors::func1()
{
    car_vector cars;
    this->cars = cars;  
}

void colors::func2()
{
    for ( car_ptr car : cars ) {
        car->price(10);
    }
}
```

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/1Pvxob7f5)

Answer (score -1):

Here a corrected version of your code, which would compile but not run:

```
class cars
{
public:
    int price(int x); // declared but not defined
}; // semicolon was missing

class colors
{
public:
   int func1(); // parenthesis was missing (member variable vs member function)
   int func2(); // parenthesis was missing (member variable vs member function)
   cars fusca; // this is actually not an error
}; // semicolon was missing

int colors::func1(/*...*/) // those 3 dots, why?
{
    //cars fusca; // this is ok, but has nothing to do with this->fusca
                  // local (blockscope) var vs member var
    //this->cars = cars; // class colors has no member cars,
                         // even if, you cannot assign a type to a member variable,
                         // but this->fusca = cars() would be ok
}

int colors::func2(/*..*/) // those 2 dots, why?
{
   this->fusca.price(10); // no problem here either (still not defined though)
}
```